# d3 donut chart transform: translateY

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am making a graph in which it shows the percentage of each data type like this:

but I have a problem copy the code and I have created it the same as the previous example but the titles put them above the percentage and I would like to fix it by placing them above the numbers as it is in the first image, since I have it like this:

This is the code where I send to call the text and in example it already throws me a transformation but I want to upload it so that it remains as a title

```
svg
      .selectAll("allLabels")
      .data(name_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .text(function (d) {
        console.log(d.data.key);
        return d.data.key;
      })
      
      .style("font-size", "1rem")
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
        pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
        return "translate(" + pos + ")";
      })
      .attr("class", "fontDonut")
      .style("text-anchor", function (d) {
        var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
        return midangle < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
      });
```

The code is like this since it is automatic and it positions itself depending on how much data there is

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 400;
var height = 250;

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = 100;

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3
  .select("#my_char")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Create dummy data
var data = {
  "25%": 25,
  "30%  ": 30,
  "20%": 20,
  "25% ": 25
}
var name = {
  "Married": 30,
  "Divorced": 30,
  "Single": 40,
  "Single2 ": 25
}

// set the color scale
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal([`#C8DBFB`, `#93B6F8`, `#256EF1`]);

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));
var name_ready = pie(d3.entries(name));

// The arc generator
var arc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.6) // This is the size of the donut hole
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8);

// Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
var outerArc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

// Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
svg
  .selectAll("allSlices")
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.key);
  })
  .style("opacity", 0.7);



// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
svg
  .selectAll("allLabels")
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    console.log(d.data.key);
    return d.data.key;
  })
  .style("font-size", "2rem")

  .style("font-weight", "700")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
  })
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    return midangle < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  });

svg
  .selectAll("allLabels")
  .data(name_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    console.log(d.data.key);
    return d.data.key;
  })

  .style("font-size", "1rem")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    pos[0] = radius * 0.99 * (midangle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return "translate(" + pos + ")";
  })
  .attr("class", "fontDonut")
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
    var midangle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
    return midangle < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  });
```

```css
.fontDonut {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center bg-white shadow py-6 px-6 chart-container">
  <div class="flex justify-start font-bold mb-4 ">
    <p class="font-bold ml-4">Children</p>
  </div>
  <div id="my_char" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't treat the two values as separate, but use them like a bloc instead. I used basic trigonometry to find the angle of the midpoint like you did, but then draw a line from the centre, so the label is aligned with the middle of the arc and all labels are the same distance from the donut.

Then, I don't have to fiddle with the labels, and instead just add the percentage on top, with a small offset. Note that `margin` only works in HTML, not in SVG.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var width = 400;
var height = 250;

// The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
var radius = 100;

// append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
var svg = d3
  .select("#my_char")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Create dummy data
var data = {
  //"Married": 30,
  "Divorced": 30,
  "Single": 40,
  "Single2 ": 25
}

// set the color scale
var color = d3
  .scaleOrdinal([`#C8DBFB`, `#93B6F8`, `#256EF1`, `darkblue`]);

// Compute the position of each group on the pie:
var pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var data_ready = pie(d3.entries(data));

// The arc generator
var arc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.6) // This is the size of the donut hole
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.8);

// Another arc that won't be drawn. Just for labels positioning
var outerArc = d3
  .arc()
  .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
  .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

// Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.key);
  })
  .style("opacity", 0.7);

// Add the polylines between chart and labels:
const labelGroup = svg
  .selectAll(".labelGroup")
  .data(data_ready)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "labelGroup")
  // Transform the whole group, not the individual text items
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    // Get the angle
    var midAngle = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;

    // Define the radius
    var textRadius = 1.4 * radius;

    // Use trigonometry to find the correct position
    var x = Math.sin(midAngle) * textRadius;
    var y = -Math.cos(midAngle) * textRadius;
    y = Math.min(y, height / 2 - 20);
    return "translate(" + [x, y] + ")";
  })
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");

labelGroup
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.key;
  })
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "hanging")
  .attr("dy", 5)
  .style("font-size", "2rem")
  .style("font-weight", "700");

labelGroup
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.value + "%";
  })
  .attr("dy", -5)
  .style("font-size", "1rem");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div class="text-center bg-white shadow py-6 px-6 chart-container">
  <div class="flex justify-start font-bold mb-4 ">
    <p class="font-bold ml-4">Children</p>
  </div>
  <div id="my_char" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much it has worked well for me with 4 but I have a query, when I leave 3 data there is one that goes up very high and it is not noticeable, how do I modify that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'd made a mistake where the y coordinate was flipped (forgotten a minus). I've also added a limit on the offset using `y = Math.min(y, height / 2 - 20)` where 20 is a sensible value based on the height of the label. You can best prevent this by adding a margin around the figure, so that there is always at least 45 pixels (the height of the label + percentage) in space available. Then the `Math.min` will help